# Java Generic Collection of Generic Type with Bounded Wildcard

Tags: java, generics, collections, bounded-wildcard

Please help me with this:

If `Lion IS-A Animal` and given `Cage<T>`:

```
Cage<? extends Animal> c = new Cage<Lion>(); // ok,
```

but

```
Set<Cage<? extends Animal>> cc = new HashSet<Cage<Lion>>(); // not ok
```

What I don't see here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When assigning to a variable (`Set<T>`) with a non-wildcard generic type `T`, the object being assigned must have exactly `T` as its generic type (including all generic type parameters of `T`, wildcard and non-wildcard). In your case `T` is `Cage<Lion>`, which is not the same type as `Cage<? extends Animal>`.

What you can do, because `Cage<Lion>` is assignable to `Cage<? extends Animal>`, is use the wildcard type:

```
Set<? extends Cage<? extends Animal>> a = new Set<Cage<Lion>>();
```

Comment: Thank you, for me, that was the missing part.

Answer (score 6):

This is wrong because if it were allowed, then this would be legal:

```
Set<Cage<? extends Animal>> cc = new HashSet<Cage<Lion>>(); 
cc.add(new Cage<Tiger>()); // legal -- Cage<Tiger> is a Cage<? extends Animal>
```

`Cage<Tiger>` is within the bounds of the declaration, but not the definition, so this would crash.

Comment: How can Java decide whether to apply contravariance/covariance or not?

Comment: My understanding Java treats generics as invariant (but, bizarrely, treats arrays as covariant and type checks at runtime) but by writing methods with suitable wildcard (extends or super as appropriate) parameters, and a bit of casting and suppressing unchecked conversions, you can give the impression of whichever is appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
Set<? extends List<? extends Number>> cc = new HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

To explain why... I guess back up to a simpler version of your example:

```
Number a = new Integer(1); // OK
Set<Number> b = new HashSet<Integer>(); // not OK
```

this doesn't work because it would allow

```
b.add(new Double(3.0));
```